# Best way to push a div up into another without absolute positioning

Tags: css, html, absolute

Here's the effect I'm trying to achieve.

[image removed - client template]

At the moment, I'm using position:absolute to push the content section up into the slideshow, however, I can't make the wrapper identify the height without setting it manually.  The content section needs to be dynamic (client will be updating this).  So, ideally, I'm looking for a way to avoid using position:absolute with top: -115px etc.  This problem also affects the footer.  If I put a footer at the bottom, it also won't recognize the height, so instead of placing it below, it assumes it's spot is right below the slideshow (underneath the content section).

Thanks in advance for any help.  Let me know if there's anything else I need to post for clarity.

Bc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `margin-top: -115px`?

Comment: I thought about that and actually used it.  I just wasn't sure if there was a better way to go about it.  Thanks for taking the time to help out!